# when i right-click on a link goes direct to the page instead of given me the options e.g: "open in a new tab"?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I want left click only go to the page and when right click, show the option?

```
<a ui-sref="app.profile({id: {{user.user_id}}})">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give `href`.

```
<a ui-sref="app.profile({id: {{user.user_id}}})" href>Edit</a>
```

Hope this is what u want!

Comment: The code above doesn't work. Currently, my situation is, when I right click, it show the option but it also go to the page profile. So I want that when I right click, it's do not go to page profile, only show the option and only when I left click then it should go to page profile.

Comment: I have just edited the answer. It has been answered by @Anj D

Comment: Sorry for the mistake @SpiderCode

Comment: In 'ui-sref ',please give the 'state' you want to go. And in 'href' give the 'url'.

Comment: Also do not work when I put some url in href.. @AnjD